# Unloading a .NET COM Interop library from native code

Tags: .net, dll, com, com-interop

I have a C#.NET DLL that contains a `ComVisible(true)` class.  I can register/call/unregister this library without any problems.

However the scenario that I want involves a native process extracting the DLL into a temporary folder, registering it, running some functions, unregistering, and finally deleting the DLL, all in a reasonably short span of time.

(Using registration-free COM would be nice, but I don't have control over the DLL location or the manifests.)

This all works fine up until the deletion part.  It seems that something in the framework keeps the DLL locked until the process exits, even if I have released all references to any objects and called `CoFreeUnusedLibraries`.

Is there some other trick to getting native code to completely unload the CLR and/or release the COM assembly (and any of its referenced assemblies)?  Or perhaps running it in a separate process?

Note that I don't have direct access to the native code, only a scripting layer on top of it, so I can make a few extra WinAPI calls but not eg. change the flags passed to CoCreateInstance etc.

Comment: I think it is not possible due the fact that an assembly cannot be unloaded if it is loaded into an AppDomain.

Comment: Right, but is it possible to unload all the managed AppDomains from native code?

Comment: I did not test, but try with `AppDomain.Unload(domain);`